# Incremental Slides with Code/Figures in Rmarkdown to Beamer Presentation

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer, presentation

I'm trying to output a beamer_presentation in Rmarkdown, where I'd like to show a code chunk, and then, on click, show the figure as a result of that code chunk. I know "xarigan" package allows this fairly simply (--), but I'd prefer to use base Rmarkdown, for reproducibility purposes.

Example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "BP"
output: beamer_presentation
---

## Slide with Bullets

- Making a plot

    ```{r cars, echo= TRUE}
     plot(cars$speed, cars$distance)
    ```
````

Ideally, the presentation would show the bullet and the code chunk, and then, incrementally build the plot.

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: I believe I have edited the code chunk to do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the definition of the `Shaded` environment a bit

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "BP"
output: 
    beamer_presentation:
        keep_tex: true
header-includes:
   - \renewenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}\pause}        
---

## Slide with Bullets

- Making a plot

    ```{r cars, echo= TRUE}
     plot(cars$speed, cars$distance)
    ```
````

(if you don't want this for your whole document, do this in a group around your plot)